# create a grouped array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a big array (read from a file)

```
$data = array(
   array(134, 'Field_A_134', 'Field_B_134'),
   array(134, 'Field_C_134', 'Field_D_134'),
   array(134, 'Field_E_134', 'Field_F_134'),
   array(180, 'Field_A_180', 'Field_B_180'),
   array(70, 'Field_A_70', 'Field_B_70'),
   array(180, 'Field_C_180', 'Field_D_180'),
   ...
);
```

and i want to group into another array by the first key from the first array (ex: 134, 180, 70, ...). Those keys are repeating, but the fields are different.

The array i want to make is:

```
array(
     '134' => array(array(134, 'Field_A_134', 'Field_B_134'), array(134, 'Field_C_134', 'Field_D_134'), array(134, 'Field_E_134', 'Field_F_134')),
     '180' => array(array(180, 'Field_A_180', 'Field_B_180'), array(180, 'Field_C_180', 'Field_D_180')),
     '70' => array(array(70, 'Field_A_180', 'Field_B_180'))
);
```

Each key contains an array of arrays that contain the first key.

I was trying to make this:

```
$f = array();
$pr = array();
foreach($data as $p){
   if(isset($f[$p[0]])){
     array_push($f[$p[0]], $p);
   } else {
     $f[$p[0]] = $p;
   }
   array_push($pr, $f);
}
```

but it`s not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `else` part. You need to assign an array, like this:

```
 $f[$p[0]] = [$p];
```

Or like this, since PHP will create the array on the fly:

```
 $f[$p[0]][] = $p;
```

And since that code can also be used when the array already exists, you can simplify to this loop:

```
foreach($data as $p) {
    $f[$p[0]][] = $p;
}
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ee34b6371407d58eb99b2dfabc75fc541f9d70e )))